# apache arrow java parquet to csv conversion and vice versa

Tags: java, apache-arrow

I am looking for an example of converting a parquet file to csv and vice versa. I am missing things like how to set the delimiter (comma or tab), how to specify date and timestamp formats (when reading from csv) and things like that.

Looked at arrow source and examples and I can't find anything for the java implementation.